# Python, Sympy and elliptic curves

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, proof, elliptic-curve

I am trying to write a simple implementation of elliptic curves in python.

So I have a simple Elliptic Curve class:

```
class EllipticCurve:

    O ="O";

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, EllipticCurve):
            return self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b
        return NotImplemented

    def __ne__(self, other):
        result = self.__eq__(other)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            return result
        return not result

    @property
    def discriminant(self):
        return 4*a**3+27*b**2
```

and a class for Points on an Elliptic Curves:

```
class Point:

def __init__(self,ec):
    self.ec = ec
    self = ec.O

def __init__(self,ec,x,y):
    self.ec = ec
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def __add__(self, other):

    if self.ec != other.ec:
        raise ValueError('These points are on different curves')
    if self == self.ec.O:
        return Point(ec, other.x, other.y)
    if other == self.ec.O:
        return Point(ec, self.x, self.y)
    if self.x==other.x and self.y==-other.y:
        return O
    if self==other:
        k = 3*(self.x**2+self.ec.a)/(2*self.y)
        x3 = k**2-self.x-other.x
        return Point(self.ec, x3,k*(self.x-x3)-self.y)

    k = (other.y-self.y)/(other.x-self.x)
    x3 = k ** 2 - self.x - other.x
    return Point(self.ec, x3, k*(self.x - x3) - self.y)

def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Point):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y and self.ec == other.ec
    return NotImplemented

def __ne__(self, other):
    result = self.__eq__(other)
    if result is NotImplemented:
        return result
    return not result

def __neg__(self):
    if self==self.ec.O:
        return O
    return Point(E,self.x,-self.y)

def __sub__(self, other):
    return self + -other
```

and although I would like to add some functionalities to them, they work with actual int values for a,b and x,y.

However, my problem is when I try to use sympy and use 'symbols' for a,b and x,y.
Ideally, my goal is to computationally prove the associative property for 3 points on an elliptic curve, ie, (P+Q)+R = P+(Q+R).

Now, I am able to get a correct result for P+Q:

```
a,b = symbols('a b')
x1,y1 = symbols('x1 y1')
x2,y2 = symbols('x2 y2')
x3,y3 = symbols('x3 y3')

E = EllipticCurve(a,b)
P = Point(E,x1,y1)
Q = Point(E,x2,y2)
R = Point(E,x3,y3)

P+Q

print(simplify((P+Q).x))
```

which outputs, correctly:

> -x1 - x2 + (y1 - y2)**2/(x1 - x2)**2

Moreover, if I do this:

```
expr = (P+Q)+R
print(simplify(expr.x))
```

I get, also (I think) correctly:

> x1 + x2 - x3 + (y1 + y3 - (y1 - y2)*(2*x1 + x2 - (y1 - y2)**2/(x1 - x2)**2)/(x1 - x2))**2/(x1 + x2 + x3 - (y1 - y2)**2/(x1 - x2)**2)**2 - (y1 - y2)**2/(x1 - x2)**2

However, if I do:

```
expr = (P+Q)+R
expr2 = P+(Q+R)

print(simplify((expr-expr2).x))
```

It takes forever, and if I try:

```
expr = (P+Q)+R
expr2 = P+(Q+R)

print((expr-expr2).x)
```

It also return an expression that seems reasonable and I think correct.
But I need to simplify it and to return 0 to prove that expr and expr2 are equal.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Your last algorithm (the one that prints 200k chars) has an extra `)` on the end of the print.

Comment: that's true... and its output is I think reasonable, however, I want to simplify it and get 0, in order to prove that the two expressions are equal and I am not able to do it....

Comment: Putting the last algorithm before the third one (the one which takes forever) I don't get 200k characters. The third one though, how long does it take to finish? I think it's been going now for 15 minutes and still nothing. (result of #4: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ParityError/e54468e5e3a88cbd6fe67ab137e77c6c/raw/2d33638eb87a5ef35676360caef54bcefe2f4916/output.log)

Comment: I got the same for #4! But the problem is I want to know if expr and expr2 are equal (in order to prove the associative property) and in order to so i need to simplify the difference of the two equations and see if I obtain 0... And it just wouldn't return

Comment: Yes, and unfortunately I think it's the `simplify()` which is creating some issue there.

Comment: any suggestions on what I should try ?

Comment: The only suggestion I might have is if there is a way you can break the formula into pieces somehow (as it currently consumes 100% of the CPU seemingly forever?). Maybe trying to use simplify there isn’t the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

> print((expr-expr2).x)

Probably you can't get 0 in a general case, because your result expression depends on x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, which don't depend on each other, and if these points do not belong to the same elliptic curve, the result will not be 0. If you try to use (expr-expr2).x.subs ... using different args xi, yi, you can check that (expr-expr2).x is not zero constant.